# Mutating a struct in its subscript getter

Tags: swift, struct, syntax

While playing with structs, I discovered the following:

```
struct SomeStruct {
    private(set) var uncount: Int
    subscript(i: Int) -> Int {
        uncount = i  // <--'self' is immutable-----
        return 3
    }
}

let someStructInstance = SomeStruct(uncount: 3)
someStructInstance[345]
```

The above code does not compile, because 'self is immutable', and you can't add mutating keyword to the subscript.

However, the following works perfectly:

```
struct SomeStruct {
    private(set) var uncount: Int
    subscript(i: Int) -> Int {
        get {
            return 3
        }
        set {
            uncount = i  //<--works well now---
        }
    }
}

let someStructInstance = SomeStruct(uncount: 3)
someStructInstance[345]
```

The question: when both the subscript functions mutate the struct property, why does one work, but not the other ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your

```
subscript(i: Int) -> Int {
    uncount = i  // <--'self' is immutable-----
    return 3
}
```

defines only a subscript *getter,* and that is *non-mutating* by default.

If you really need to mutate the property in the getter then
you can declare it as `mutating get`:

```
subscript(i: Int) -> Int {
    mutating get {
        uncount = i
        return 3
    }
}
```

As a consequence, the getter cannot be used with a constant value
anymore,

```
let someStructInstance = SomeStruct(uncount: 3)
print(someStructInstance[345])
// error: Cannot use mutating getter on immutable value: 'someStructInstance' is a 'let'
```

it has to be a variable:

```
var someStructInstance = SomeStruct(uncount: 3)
print(someStructInstance[345])     // 3
print(someStructInstance.uncount)  // 345
```

Comment: Getters with side effects... :/